# Glue Table does not exist in catalog

Tags: python, aws-lambda, etl, aws-glue

I am converting json file to parquet format but get the error "Glue Table does not exist" Here is the code:

```
 

  import awswrangler as wr
  import pandas as pd
  import urllib.parse
  import os
 

  os_input_s3_file_path = os.environ['s3_cleaned_layer']
  os_input_glue_catalog_db_name = os.environ['glue_catalog_db_name']
  os_input_glue_catalog_table_name = os.environ['glue_catalog_table_name']
  os_input_write_data_operation = os.environ['write_data_operation']

  def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
     #Get object and key name
     bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
     key= urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']
                 ['key'], encoding = 'utf-8')             
    
     try:
        
         #creating df from content
         df_raw = wr.s3.read_json('s3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, key))
        
         #get item from raw df
         df_step_1 = pd.json_normalize(df_raw['items'])
        
         #write to s3
         wr_response = wr.s3.to_parquet(
             df=df_step_1,
             dataset=True,
             database=os_input_glue_catalog_db_name,
             table=os_input_glue_catalog_table_name,
             mode=os_input_write_data_operation
             )
        
         return wr_response
        
     except Exception as e:
         print(e)
         print('Error getting object {}  {}'.format(key, bucket))
         raise e
```

I have added the environment variables in the configuration tab.

Policies attached: Amazons3fullaccess, Amazonglueservicerole

Expecting a parquet format file created in a new bucket

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying code like that:

```py
wr_response = wr.s3.to_parquet(
   df=df_step_1,
   path='s3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, os_input_glue_catalog_table_name)
   dataset=True,
   database=os_input_glue_catalog_db_name,
   table=os_input_glue_catalog_table_name,
   mode=os_input_write_data_operation
)
```

Check function manual: https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.s3.to_parquet.html

Maybe parquet table also required: https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.catalog.create_parquet_table.html

Also take a look at that  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/fine-grained-access-to-glue-resources.html

Comment: this is the error:

{  "errorMessage": "Glue table does not exist in the catalog. Please pass the `path` argument to create it.",  "errorType": "InvalidArgumentValue",  "stackTrace": [    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 40, in lambda_handler\n    raise e\n",    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 27, in lambda_handler\n    wr_response = wr.s3.to_parquet(\n",    "  File \"/opt/python/awswrangler/_config.py\", line 735, in wrapper\n    return function(**args)\n",    "  File \"/opt/python/awswrangler/_utils.py\",

Comment: OK, so it's not Athena the problem. Try adding that line `path='s3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, os_input_glue_catalog_table_name)` to `wr.s3.to_parquet`

Comment: Now I am getting this error:
{
  "errorMessage": "No files Found on: s3://de-yt-useast1-raw-dev/cleaned_statistics_refrenced_data.",
  "errorType": "NoFilesFound",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 38, in lambda_handler\n    raise e\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 19, in lambda_handler\n    df_raw = wr.s3.read_json('s3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, os_input_glue_catalog_table_name))\n",

Comment: These are the environment variables:
[glue_catalog_db_name     de-yt-clean]
[glue_catalog_table_name   cleaned_statistics_refrenced_data]
[s3_cleaned_layer    s3://de-yt-useast1-cleaned-dev/youtube]
[write_data_operation   append]

Comment: Have you tried this: https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.catalog.create_parquet_table.html